# How to store boost::bind object as member variable?

Tags: c++, boost, bind, functor

I am using boost::bind to create composed functions on-the-fly, and hope to store the object as some class member variable for later usage. For example we have two functors:

```
struct add{double operator()(double x, double y) const{return x+y;};};  
struct multiply{double operator()(double x, double y) const{return x*y;};};
```

Then to create a function f(x,y,z) = (x+y)*z, I can do this:

```
auto f = boost::bind<double>(multiply(), boost::bind<double>(add(), _1, _2), _3);
```

And calling f(x,y,z) works perfectly. Now I want to save f as a class member variable, something like the following:

```
struct F  
{  
  auto func;  
  double operator(const std::vector<double>& args) const  
  {  
    return func(args[0],args[1],args[2]); //Skipping boundary check  
  }  
}

F f_obj;  
f_obj.func = f;  
f_obj(args);
```

But of course I cannot declare an auto variable. Is there any way to get around this?

Note that I am not using boost::function, as it will dramatically impact the performance, which is important to me.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

Two options: use `boost::function`, and measure whether it actually affects performance.

Alternatively make F a template taking the type of `func`  as parameter and deduce it from the type of the `bind` expression.

EDIT: The problem with the second option is it doesn't get rid of the awkward type. You can do that by defining a base class with a pure virtual function which the template overrides. But then you have dynamic memory to manage and the cost of a virtual function to pay - so you might as well go back to `boost::function` (or `std::function`) which does much the same thing for you.

Comment: boost::function is exactly the first thing I tried, but compiler cannot inline the boost::function wrapper. From my test, using boost::function is ~5 times slower than native code, while using boost::bind directly has no observable overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The type returned from `bind()` is specific to each combination of function objects and arguments. If you want to store the result, you will need to erase the type in some way. The obvious approach is to use `function<..>`.

When the resulting function object is invoked frequently, the overhead introduced by `function<...>` effectively doing a virtual dispatch may be too high. One approach to counter the problem is to bundle the function object with suitable bulk operations and instead of storing the function object to store a suitable application. That won't help when individual calls are needed but when lots of calls are required the virtual dispatch is paid just once.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Could you give an example how it is implemented?